# I want to generate multiple tables for each order/s using asp repeater

Tags: c#, asprepeater

Currently I have a table that binds all the orders from SQL using asp repeater in ONE TABLE. My problem is I cannot find a way to separate the orders by generating MULTIPLE TABLES that are sorted out by tracking number using asp repeater. Is this method possible? If so, How?

[My current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNvtV.png)

## ASP Repeater

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>

            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    My Accepted Orders
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Tracking Number</th>
                            <th>Order Type</th>
                            <th>Job Name</th>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>

                        </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("Tracking_Number") %></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Order") %><%--<img src="<%#Eval("FrontImg")%> " height="50" width="50" --%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Job_Name") %></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Date_Created") %></td>
                 <td><%#Eval("Due_Date") %></td> 
                <td><%#Eval("Quantity") %></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Price") %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnPayment" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("OID") %>' CommandName="Payment" runat="server" Text="Payment" CssClass="btn btn-primary"  />
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
                         
                        </div> 
</div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

## Code Behind

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bindtoAcceptedOrders();
    }
}

private void bindtoAcceptedOrders()
{

    string UserID = hfUserID.Value;

  
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);

   
    string cmdText = "SELECT * From Order_TB where UID=@UID and Status=@status";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UserID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Accepted");

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }


    Repeater1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Repeater1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: It's possible, you need a repeater, whose item template is a repeater. The outer rptr. needs to bind to a collection of inner rptr. bound objects. However, this is verbose and complex to maintain, I once did it. You end up having to plug workarounds into the strict workflow of Web Forms. You will do this in a lot quicker and cleaner with MVC, in fact it will be easier too, even if you haven't done MVC before, also your queries are hand written and this would slow you down too, you can add an EF data model from your database and use LINQ to SQL. I'd invest 1 hour into a youtube video on MVC.

Comment: Too bad I cannot switch to MVC because the website that I am developing using web form is almost done.  I heard a lot about  how easy and efficient MVC  is. But I'll consider that next time. Can you give me an example code for inner and outer repeater ? Thanks!